# Determination of electromagnetic wave absorption by molecular vibration mode

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics, molecules, dipole, dipole-moment

In [this physics.stackexchange answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/16264/17354), it is stated that the absorption of electromagnetic wave at a given wavelength by a molecule is determined by its vibration modes. What is the exact equation/Hamiltonian, either classical electrodynamical or quantum mechanical, that governs the process?